Time Steps in Unity (C#)
I'm writing some C# code for my unity game to move an object to the left. An online tutorial told me that I need to multiply my position transformation by deltaTime in order to ensure that computers which run on different frame rates still move my object at the same rate, independently of their frame rate and instead based on time.
Here is the code:
void Update()
{
    transform.posititon = transform.position + (Vector3.left * moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
}

What I am confused about is how does multiplying Time.deltaTime guarantee that we will not still be affected by framerate? Since we are not dividing or otherwise getting rid of any framerate parameter, wouldn't multiplying Time.deltaTime simply confound the issue?
I followed an online tutorial and that's what it instructed me to do, but I would like to know why.

deltaTime is simply the time since the last update. If more time passed (lower framerate) you get more movement to compensate. So if you have 100 fps for example you get 100 small movements per second and if you run at 10 fps you get fewer, bigger movements.

in simple words: because multiplication by deltaTime means the same as dividing by the frame rate

Just realized this has an obvious answer haha, because since fps is counted in frames per second higher frame rates will run with lower deltaTime values (60 fps -> 1/60 seconds (about 0.016 seconds) between frames) and lower frame rates will run with higher deltaTime values (30 fps -> 1/30 seconds (about 0.033 seconds) between frames) so that's how multiplying by deltaTime cancels the frames out and yields only units in seconds! I forgot fps = f/s

deltatime is amount of time between two frames. so if a lot have passed since last update, then you move a lot more.
so if your speed is 1
if you have a slow device and it can do 1 frame per second, then deltatime becomes 1 and and you move 1 in every second
if you have a fast machine with 100 frames per second then delta time becomes 0.01 and you move 0.01 in every frame which becomes 1 in every second.
so your game will move the same no matter how fast your computer is.
also you should probably read about fixedUpdate and fixedDeltaTime. great next step.

also you should probably read about fixedUpdate and fixedDeltaTime. great next step. ... Why? ^^

@derHugo since unlike is has something to do with input handling at any point, FixedUpdate is more sensical since it doesnt mess with other objects that are physics simulated. also is make the game synced and things like follow jitters are minimalized.

Not really .. if this is not a physics object (and it doesn't seem so for now) then only moving it in fixed intervals might even be more off and jitter and interfere with other code that is update on a frame wise basis ...

The simplest answer is that it makes the variable relative to the speed of your device. High FPS makes the variable higher and the same goes for low FPS.

The Update method is called every frame, so your fps, frames per second, is the amount of times Update is called per second.

Let's imagine your game is played on 2 different devices: the 1st one with 30, and the 2nd one with 60 frames per second.
Update is going to be called 30 and 60 times per second for each device respectively.
The following code in Update increases the character's position by 10 on every axis. As we have already discussed, the character's position is thus increased by 10 every frame.
transform.position += Vector2.one * 10f;

When using this code on the 1st device with 30 fps, Update is going to be called 30 times, each producing the position increase of 10. This gives us the total of

10 * 30 = 300 for the 1st, and
10 * 60 = 600 for the 2nd device per second.

This means, at the end of the second, the 2nd device's character is going to be moved twice as far as the 1st one's. This doesn't sound pretty fair, especially when having a multiplayer.

According to Unity's documentation, Time.deltaTime is

The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one.

Time.deltaTime returns the value, which represents 1 divided by your current fps.
Additionally, it also returns Time.fixedDeltaTime when called from FixedUpdate.
This means, it's going to be

1 / 30 = 0.0(3) for the 1st, and
1 / 60 = 0.01(6) for the 2nd device.

If now calculate what it gives for both devices per second, it's going to be

1 / 30 * 30 = 1 for the 1st, and
1 / 60 * 60 = 1 for the 2nd device.

As you see, both values are the same.

Let us modify the previous code by also multiplying it by Time.deltaTime. Note that the order is important for performance.
transform.position += 10f * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.one;

Now the position increase per frame is going to be

10 * 1 / 30 = 0.(3) for the 1st, and
10 * 1 / 60 = 0.1(6) for the 2nd device.

This results in the same position increase per second:

10 * 1 / 30 * 30 = 10 for the 1st, and
10 * 1 / 60 * 60 = 10 for the 2nd device.


Of course, Time.deltaTime changes every single frame, as you may have already noticed when tracking your game's fps.
However, the calculation mistake is small enough for you to not notice it at all, and it will always result in nearly the same result calculated on different devices.
